# How to remove several different stems at the end of the word using slicing

Tags: python

Although I understand there are tools such as NLTK to do this for me, however, I would like to understand how I can slice several stems within a list efficiently.

Say my list of words is;

```
list = ["another", "cats", "walrus", "relaxed", "annoyingly", "rest", "normal", "hopping", "classes", "wing", "feed"]
```

And my common stems I would like to remove may be;

```
stems = ["s", "es", "ed", "est", "ing", "ly"] etc
```

With words I do not want stemmed specified as;

```
noStem = ["walrus", "rest", "wing", "feed"]
```

I have worked out how to do it for one specific stem like "s". For example, my code would be;

```
for eachWord in list:
    if eachWord not in noStem:
       if eachWord[-1] == "s":
           eachWord = eachWord[:-1]

stemmedList = stemmedList + [eachWord]
```

I am not sure how I would apply this to all my stems in a more efficient way.

Thanks for your help and advice!

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you convert `noStem` to a `set` so that the check `if eachWord not in noStem` is fast. Then you can check if the word `endswith` any stem in `stems`. If it does, you can use the largest stem that matches and remove it from the word:

```
lst = ["another", "cats", "walrus", "relaxed", "annoyingly", "rest", "normal", "hopping", "classes", "wing", "feed"]
stems = ["s", "es", "ed", "est", "ing", "ly"]
noStem = {"walrus", "rest", "wing", "feed"}
stemmedList = []

for word in lst:
    if word in noStem or not any([word.endswith(stem) for stem in stems]):
        stemmedList.append(word)
    else:
        stem = max([s for s in stems if word.endswith(s)], key=len)
        stemmedList.append(word[:len(word) - len(stem)])

print(stemmedList)
# ['another', 'cat', 'walrus', 'relax', 'annoying', 'rest', 'normal', 'hopp', 'class', 'wing', 'feed']
```

Answer (score 0):

I think that isn't a bad start. You just need to add the second loop to be able to work with multiple endings. You can try something like below, (You'll notice I've renamed the variable `list` because it's dangerous having variables shadowing built-in names)

```
stemmed_list = []
for word in word_list:
    if word not in noStem:
        for ending in stems:
            if word.endswith(ending):
                 word = word[:-len(ending)]
                 break   # This will prevent iterating over all endings once match is found
    stemmed_list.append(word)
```

Or if as per your comment you don't want to use `endswith`

```
stemmed_list = []
for word in word_list:
    if word not in noStem:
        for ending in stems:
            if word[-len(ending):] == ending:
                 word = word[:-len(ending)]
                 break   # This will prevent iterating over all endings once match is found
    stemmed_list.append(word)
```

Comment: Thank you for this comment, this is the idea I was aiming for. If I may ask a second question, is it possible to do this without the endswith() method? I'd like to use a slice constructor to make this work.

Comment: @highfocus that is possible (see my edit) although I don't necessarily know why you would want to as endswith is a nice built-in convenience method

Answer (score 0):

It's much more complicated than this but here goes a starter code using much faster pandas module. Here it goes.

```
import pandas as pd
import re

word_list = ["another", "cats", "walrus", "relaxed", "annoyingly", "rest", "normal", "hopping", "classes", "wing", "feed"]

stems = ["es",  "ed", "est", "ing", "ly", "s"]

# a set for quick lookup 
noStem = set(["walrus", "rest", "wing", "feed"])

# build series
words = pd.Series(word_list)

# filter out words in noStem
words = words[words.apply(lambda x: x not in noStem)]

# compile regular explession - performance - join all stems for matching
term_matching = '|'.join(stems)
expr = re.compile(r'(.+?)({})$'.format(term_matching))

df = words.str.extract(expr, expand=True)
df.dropna(how='any', inplace=True)
df.columns = ['words', 'stems']

stemmed_list = df.words.tolist()
```

I hope it helps ...